# Paypal API for iOS

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am working on iOS project in which their is the functionality like users can directly sell product to other users. I have integrated Paypal API for do payment. I did R&D on this topics and I found that I need to implement Adaptive PAI rather then simple payment API.
I have integrated below paypal SDK:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

In this there is the method for simple payment and parallel payment but there is no methods for fund transfer or adaptive payment. So if anyone have idea regarding how I can directly transfer money from buyer to seller account then please give me some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think adaptive payment is yet to be supported in paypal iOS API. You can raise bug on their Github repo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using the newer "Mobile SDK" which is built on the REST API and doesn't fully support Adaptive Payments yet.  Instead, you want the "[Mobile Payment Library (MPL)](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL)" which is built on the Classic API and does support all the features.

You can find more details about the two here:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/

Comment: Yes, we have checked the details provided by you. Its very useful, thanks for this. We have checked sample code of GitHub for Adaptive payment but it contains some error, I guess i haven't configured it properly. If you have small demo project for this Adaptive payment then it will be much better.

Comment: All my samples would be PHP.